# Django Rest Framework how to disable authentication and authorization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a system in `Django` without using any of its batteries -- `auth`, `admin` etc. The system uses the `Django` rest framework for the API.

However, when I try to request to an API, I keep getting this error:

```
Model class django.contrib.auth.models.Permission doesn't declare an explicit
app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I do not want to use `django.contrib.auth` at all. I did the following inside my DRF API View class:

```
class NewsPostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = None

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        posts = NewsPost.objects.all()
        serializer = NewsPostSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response([])
```

However, I am still getting the same error. How can I disable auth from DRF?

Comment: show us your settings.py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved my issue. After @Linovia's response, I checked the docs etc of DRF and changed the following properties:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = { 
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
    'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER': None,
}
```

And everything worked.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, you could make it explicit that this configuration goes inside REST_FRAMEWORK settings. Specifically 
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
    'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER': None,
}

Answer (score 6):

Use `AllowAny` instead of `None`. And also your response seems to be returning empty list. use `serializer.data` for retrieving  data

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

class NewsPostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        posts = NewsPost.objects.all()
        serializer = NewsPostSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't use `rest_framework.urls` and that your settings has:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': tuple(),
```

as well as your views.
With some luck, you won't have the authentication imported through another import.